Windows 11 native ssh.exe doesn't show a password prompt in some cases (emacs)
I am trying to use emacs tramp via /ssh: which calls Windows 11's native ssh client. It hangs. Reading logs, it seems ssh.exe never serves the password prompt username@hostname's password:  to tramp, so tramp hangs until timeout.
It works fine to install putty and just use /plink:, but this is a new dependency.
Through powershell or cmd.exe, the same ssh.exe gives the prompt + connects fine.
As an experiment I tried using ssh.exe through emacs eshell with the same problem.
Output of ssh.exe user@hostname -vvv -tt is identical in cmd and eshell except that in eshell the password prompt is omitted. Adding RequestTTY force for hostname in client SSH config doesn't affect things.
Is this a problem with Windows or emacs?

GNU Emacs 29.3, Windows 11, ssh.exe -V gives  OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3.

ssh.exe expects the password to be entered from a TTY.

I wonder if it's possible to have it get password through an auth agent instead

Then I think this is a ssh.exe question.

The Tramp manual says:
4.19.5 Issues with Cygwin and MS Windows ssh
MS Windows' ‘ssh’ does not open a remote TTY.  Use the method
‘sshx’ or ‘scpx’ instead.  Furthermore, it cannot read a passphrase
for ssh private keys.  Use the MS ‘ssh-agent’.
